# Efficient way of doing multiple case when statements with a groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something like this efficiently in Pandas

SQL version

```
select account_ID
,sum(case when FAIL = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Fail
,sum(case when SUCCESS = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Success
,sum(case when Reason LIKE '%Hard%' or Reason LIKE '%Missed%' then 1 else 0) as Reason
from df
group by account_ID
```

Pandas Version

```
a= df.groupby('ACCOUNT_ID').sum()['FAIL'].to_frame()
b= df.groupby('ACCOUNT_ID').sum()['SUCCESS'].to_frame()
Reason= df.groupby('ACCOUNT_ID').sum['SUCCESS'] -- No idea how to do Reason 
c = pd.merge(a,b,left_index=True,right_index=True)
d = pd.merge(c,Reason,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Output

[image: Output Table]

```
account_id  Fail    Success Reason
1           1       0       AHard
1           0       1       Blank
1           1       0       Missed
2           0       1       Blank
2           0       1       Blank
2           0       1       Blank
2           1       0       NA
```

Output created using the input

[image]

Comment: Can you post input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, first create a counter "helper" column for reasons to defined when that reason should count or not using .str and contains with a regex then groupby and sum:

```
df['reason_cnt'] = df['Reason'].str.contains('Hard|Missed').fillna(0).astype(int)
df.groupby('account_id')[['Fail', 'Success', 'reason_cnt']].sum()
```

Output:

```
   account_id  Fail  Success  reason_cnt
0           1     2        1           2
1           2     1        3           0
```

#### One-liner

```
df.assign(reason=df['Reason'].str.contains('Hard|Miss').fillna(0).astype(int))\
  .groupby('account_id').sum()
```

#### if I were to do it using your code as a start

```
a= df.groupby('account_id')['Fail'].sum().to_frame()
b= df.groupby('account_id')['Success'].sum().to_frame()
Reason= df.assign(reason = df['Reason'].str.contains('Hard|Miss')).groupby('account_id').sum()
pd.concat([a, b, Reason], axis=1)
```

Update : You could pass `na=False` in `str.contains`; this should negate the need to change data type and `fill` :

```
(
    df.assign(reason_cnt=df.loc[:, "Reason"].str.contains("Hard|Missed", na=False))
    .groupby("account_id")[["Fail", "Success", "reason_cnt"]]
    .sum()
)
```

Comment: What's the .fillna(0) for?

Comment: The fillna handles the NaN and replace that NaN with a 0.

Comment: That assumes that that NA is a np.NaN and not as a string 'NA'.

Comment: Right that makes sense, I actually facepalmed when i saw your answer cause it's so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Let's say i wanted to add d= df.groupby('ACCOUNT_ID').avg()['FAIL'].to_frame().
Would I have to use a merge then? Or is there a one lines that puts every groupby into a dataframe?

Comment: You can use pd.concat, join, or merge.  You'd merge using left_index=True and right_index=True.   Join uses indexes, and pd.concat with axis=1 will align the data on indexes.

Comment: @Mobix See updated with your code as starting point.  I restructured the first two statements to make it idiomatic to pandas.

Comment: @sammywemmy  You know, either I forgot about that parameter or have never used `na` parameter in str.contains  Thank you for the update!